# Boundary of $S=\{(x, y) \in R \mid y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ where $R = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

$S=\{(x, y) \in R \mid y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ where $R = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$. I want to determine boundary $\partial S$ of $S$. I feel that it is $S$ itself as no point of $S$ is an interior point and $\overline{S} = R$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in saying that he interior is empty. But the boundary is the closure minus the interior. So $\partial S \neq S, \partial S=\overline S =R$.